# Definition of Bound/Free Variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, logic

You may have already seen that:

$$\int_0^1 x \, dx = \int_0^1 y \, dy$$

But the formal reason **why** this is done is because $x$ is a **bound variable** correct?

**QUESTION:** *We are allowed to change variables in substitution because $x$ was a bound variable?*

Rather than the axiomated fact that it is "dummy variable" axiom, if that it is a such thing..

[Bound & Free Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables)

Thanks!

Comment: The title and the question's body have different questions.

Comment: So $x$ is still a "free variable," which is why we can change it for another symbol?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA : It is _bound_, not _bounded_.  The quantifier does not _bound_ it; the quantifier _binds_ it.

Comment: *Substitution* is **not** the "renaming" of bound variable, but the formal process that produes the expression $\alpha(x/t)$ obtained from the formula $\alpha$ (with $x$ free) by replacing the variable $x$, wherever it occurs free in $\alpha$, by the term $t$.

Answer (score 4):

The precise formal reason why this holds depends on exactly how you formalize the integral notation. There are some choices to make along the way -- and since these choices are of no real *practical* importance when actually *doing* mathematics, nobody has bothered to forge a consensus about what the "standard" way to formalize the semi-formal everyday notation should be.

However, a reasonably mainstream approach would say that formally the (definite, Riemann) integral is an operation with three inputs, namely a lower bound, an upper bound, and a function to integrate. The usual $\int_a^b \cdots dx$ notation then does double duty of *defining* a function by integration and immediately applying the integration operator to it.

In this notation the $dx$ does indeed bind the variable $x$ within the $\cdots$.

So $\int_0^1 x\,dx$ is formally an abbreviation for $\operatorname{RiemannIntegral}(0,1,(x\in[a,b]\mapsto x))$, where $(x\in[a,b]\mapsto x)$ is an ad hoc notation for an *anonymous function*. Less ad hoc, we should probably use the *lambda calculus*, which is the most well-known formalization of speaking about functions defined by expression. In that case, our anonymous function would be written $(\lambda x\in[a,b].x)$. But if one insists of sticking with semi-formal everyday set theory as the formalism, we would write $\{\langle x,x\rangle\mid x\in[a,b]\}$.

Because the name of the dummy variable doesn't matter, then the anonymous function $\lambda x\in[a,b].x$ is identical to $\lambda y\in[a,b].y$. This is the *alpha conversion* axiom of the lambda calculus.

---

According to the formalism just sketched, when we write "$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$", what we actually get is $\operatorname{RiemannIntegral}(a,b,\lambda x\in[5,7].f(x))$ -- but (at least if we ignore uninteresting pedantry about the domain) $\lambda x.f(x)$ is *the same function* as $f$ (this is the *eta conversion* rule of the lambda calculus), so that is the same thing as $\operatorname{RiemannIntegral}(a,b,f)$.

(If you want to be pedantic, define $f|_A$ as notation for $\lambda x\in A.f(A)$, and prove that $\operatorname{RiemannIntegral}(a,b,f)=\operatorname{RiemannIntegral}(a,b,g)$ whenever $f|_{[a,b]}=g|_{[a,b]}$. Then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=\operatorname{RiemannIntegral}(a,b,f)$ is a bona fide theorem even if the domain of $f$ is "too large").

---

Note that changing the variable name by alpha-renaming is something different and more primitive than the rule taught as "integration by substitution". The latter is, in the language of function-based formalism, about *composition* -- namely, under appropriate conditions it says formally that
$$ \operatorname{RiemannIntegral}(g(a),g(b),f)=\operatorname{RiemannIntegral}(a,b,(f\circ g)\cdot g') $$
and this wording doesn't mention any names for the variable of integration at all.

Comment: I just want to add that the notation $\displaystyle \int \limits_a^b f$ is also standard and avoids all these issues.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I am still confused. I do not know about Lambda calculus etc... I am talking about standard calculus. I looked up alpha renaming, no results. But in simple high school language, what allows change of variables? Or is it axiomated or definition?

Comment: @anonymous: In a simple high school setting, the integral notation _is not part of a formal system at all_. Thus it makes little sense to ask what precise axioms allows this rewriting (which everybody agrees _is_ allowed). If you want to have precise axioms, you need to _make_ the notation into a formal system -- and while you do that it is your job as a designer of the formal system to make sure that it allows the rewritings it needs to allow, such as change of variable names. It's up to you _how_ you achieve that, among the several possible ways to do it. My suggestion is not the only one.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I am utterly confused. I am not trying to create math all over again, and I am not trying to create new notation etc.. I am simply asking why it is possible to change variables?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, actually, are we actually just using simple let $x=a$ substitutions?

Comment: @anonymous: The notation already exists, but if you want a _formalization_ of it where you can point to a particular axiom or rule for changing variables names, you have to choose one yourself -- there's no particular choice in this area that the Governing Council of Mathematics has declared to be the canonical one. If, on the other hand, you _don't_ care about pointing to a particular formalized axiom for changing variable names, then that's fine -- just keep doing it for the pragmatic reason that it obviously makes no difference what the variable is called.

Comment: You don't _need_ to point to a formal written-down axiom to know that it doesn't matter what the variable is called. The fact that it doesn't matter what the variable is called is _just how notation works_. If you're interested in how to formalize that fact, that's fine -- I've given you my answer to that. If you're not particularly interested in formalization, then that's fine too -- you don't need one to do everyday mathematics in practice and the notation is from before modern concepts of how formal systems ought to work was even invented anyway.

Comment: But it seems that you want to have your cake and eating it too -- you keep asking which rule allows the rewriting, but at the same time you don't want an answer that speaks about rules. It is not possible to answer that question under that constraint.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I am sorry, I meant I didnt want to go too advance, only an understanding. You said: " The fact that it doesn't matter what the variable is called is just how notation works"  Is that for all math? In equations, integrals, sums etc..?  SO its just the notation? but I have never been taught this before?

Comment: @HenningMakholm This is confusing because Michael Hardy said it is due to bound variables, but here you are saying it is notation?

Answer (score -1):

It is correct that one can rename the variable because it is a bound (or "dummy") variable.  However, if the letter $y$ were being used in the context in which you are writing to refer to something other than the bound variable in this integral, then it should not be used as the new name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is from definition correct?